# separating my code by certain time intervals in R

Tags: r, benchmarking

I am working on geocoding a large dataset in R (about 18,000 observations) and because of the query limit I need to set up a timer for my geocoding. I have been searching the web pretty extensively but everything I have read has been very confusing. Am I supposed to create a function first that does this then use that function along with my geocoding function? Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You don't even mention if R has a geolocation feature. So,I bet you haven't even tried that, if it has. If it hasn't then that's your answer and you should find a tool that can do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You want to suspend execution of R code? Then you should use this function:

```
Sys.sleep(time)
```

`time` in seconds.